# Нужна ли дополнительная память для работы service worker?

Tags: javascript, pwa, indexeddb

Планируется создать PWA на React, которое позволяет отправлять большое количество файлов, ориентировочно до 100. И каждый файл весит по 10 Мб.

Есть input file. Мы открываем нативное окно и выбираем все 100 файлов. Браузер фиксирует их месторасположение на телефоне. Память прим этом не расходуется же?

Если во время отправки файлов на сервер, например, пропадает интернет. То процесс отправки приостанавливается и service worker через определенные интервалы снова пытается отправить.

Вопрос - для его работы не нужна дополнительная память на телефоне? Не нужно ли для этого использовать Indexed DB, как вариант?

Возможно процесс отправки стоит построить как-то по другому.

Comment: Тут зависит от того, как вы отправляете файлы и как реализована доотправка.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko А какие есть варианты? Если самая обычная отправка через POST запрос, используя Axios? Доотправка, подразумевалась таким же способом

Comment: Пример кода будет не лишним, потому что отправить POST через AJAX тоже можно по разному.